# Exact solutions to the equation $\sin(x) = n \cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Can we precisely solve the equation $$\sin(x) = n\cos(x)$$ in $x$?

For $n=1$, we get $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: To add to the answer by @Fredrik, note that you don't lose any solutions by dividing by $\cos$ since both sides cannot be zero simultaneously.

Comment: The set of solutions is $x_n+\pi\mathbb Z$, for some $x_n$ in $[\pi/4,\pi/2)$ depending on $n\geqslant1$, such that $x_1=\pi/4$, $x_n\lt x_{n+1}$ for every $n$ and $x_n=\pi/2-1/n+o(1/n)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: By the way: 18 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only rational values of $\tan(x)$ or $\cot(x)$ for rational $x$ in degrees are $0$ and $\pm 1$. See for instance

Olmsted, J. M. H.; 
Discussions and Notes: [Rational Values of Trigonometric Functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2304540). 
Amer. Math. Monthly 52 (1945), no. 9, 507–508.

From this you cannot expect that your equation has any other nice solutions.

Comment: Related to this result is [Niven's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html).